# Is laravel-ide-helper compatible with laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

### laravel-ide-helper github: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

**When I use "composer install" throw these errors**

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.

Script php artisan ide-helper:generate handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
Error Output:

**Is laravel-ide-helper compatible with laravel 5.3?**

Answer (score 2):

adding the line 
'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider',
 in app.php 'providers' array fixed it.

Comment: ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.  
Script @php artisan ide-helper:generate handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1. 

And solve with your suggest. Thanks